# Como calcular el area de la superficie de un huevo con calculo

Tags: calculus

Estoy haciendo mi reciente evaluación interna del IB Matemáticas HL y mi tema es cómo calcular el área de superficie de un huevo . Quiero aplicar el cálculo conocimiento en esta pregunta, pero mi conocimiento sobre esta área es limitada. Sólo sé la información básica acerca de cálculo, por ejemplo, mediante la integración para calcular el volumen de un objeto. Ya he buscado información relevante en línea durante muchos días, pero todavía tengo ni idea.

**Translation (slightly cleaned-up Google Translate):** I am doing my recent internal assessment of the IB Math HL and my subject is how to calculate the surface area of an egg. I want to apply knowledge of calculus in this question, but my knowledge about this area is limited. I only know basic information about calculus, for example, by integrating to calculate the volume of an object. I have already searched for relevant information online for many days, but I still have no idea.

Comment: You will be much more likely to get help on this site if you ask your question in English.  Perhaps edit your question to include an English translation (attempt at least).

Comment: Try turning the egg sideways and developing an equation that represents (half of) the cross-section. Then take a look at surfaces of revolution.